# How to merge two sequential MySQL rows into one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can I combine two sequntial MySQL table rows into one?

For example, input:

```
Id  FName
1   Name1
2   Name2
3   Name3 
4   Name4
7   Name5
8   Name6
```

The desired output:

```
Id FName
1  Name1,Name2
3  Name3,Name4
7  Name5,Name6
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear enogh

Comment: My advice is to read up on database normalization. Good luck!

Comment: people normalize their de-normalized table. you are first person who trying to denormalize their normalize table.

Comment: @Rahul : as a software developer you have to obey the client's instructions mate!! ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can us the modulus operator(%) to pick the odd rows (by id) and a join to get the even numbered ids

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (id int, FName varchar(5));

insert into t values
(1,   'Name1'),
(2,   'Name2'),
(3,   'Name3'),
(4,   'Name4'),
(7,   'Name5'),
(8,   'Name6');

select t.id,concat(t.fname,',',t1.fname) fname
from t t
join t t1 on t1.id = t.id + 1
where t.id % 2 <> 0
```

result

```
+------+-------------+
| id   | fname       |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | Name1,Name2 |
|    3 | Name3,Name4 |
|    7 | Name5,Name6 |
+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer and brief explanation. but the only issue is that i need both odd/even rows. so in that case modulo operator won't work. but thanks for direction

Comment: I don't understand your comment the result from the solution gives your desired output?